# Collect Data from log files with logstash

Tags: logstash

I'm trying with logstash to collect data from a log file for a version of NETASQ Firewall which contains a lot of lines , but i can not collect correctly my data , I don't know if there is a standard to follow, but I started like this:

```
input {
  stdin { }
  file {
    type => "FireWall"
    path => "/var/log/file.log"
    start_position => 'beginning'
  }
}
filter {
  grok {
    match => [ "message", "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:date} %{WORD:id}"]
  }
}
output {
  stdout { }
  elasticsearch {
    cluster => "logstash"
  }
}
```

The first line of my file.log looks like this :

```
Feb 27 04:02:23 id=firewall time="2015-02-27 04:02:23" fw="GVGM-NEWYORK"
tz=+0200 startime="2015-02-27 04:02:22" pri=5 confid=01 slotlevel=2 ruleid=57
srcif="Vlan2" srcifname="SSSSS" ipproto=udp dstif="Ethernet0" 
dstifname="out" proto=teredo src=192.168.21.12 srcport=52469 
srcportname=ephemeral_fw_udp dst=94.245.121.253 dstport=3544 
dstportname=teredo dstname=teredo.ipv6.microsoft.com.nsatc.net 
action=block logtype="filter"#015
```

And finally How can I collect data from the others lines. Please give me a topic just to start. Thanks All.

Comment: Your log example is actually two lines, right? The second one beginning with "#015 Feb 27 ...".

Comment: yes you're right , but the second one beginnig with "Feb 27 04:02:23 id=firewall" ...